# How to add div with input value to the body?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function createDivTag() {
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
var div = document.getElementById("newtask");
div.innerHTML += document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
}

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your task..." required  />
<!-- some code -->
<section class="start" onclick="createDivTag();">
```

This code should create a new div element on click with a value from input, but nothing happens. What am I doling wrong? Please assist with that issue.

Comment: What is `idName` for a property?

Comment: sorry, this line shouldn't be there. don't call attention to it.

Comment: It's part of the problem code. So saying "don't call attention to it" is beyond stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like idName, it's property is 'id'

```
    function createDivTag() {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.id = "newtask";
        newDiv.innerHTML += document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
        document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
    }

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your task..." required  />
    <!-- some code -->
    <section class="start" onclick="createDivTag();">
```

Comment: Why `getElementById("newtask")` since you already have reference to that div? No need for `var div = ... ` line, You can use `newDiv` directly

Comment: Thanks. I corrected, but it still doesn't work. I tried to replace [+= document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value] for [+= "some text"] - nothing happens either.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add the new element something. In this example I have added the new div to the body, but you can change it to some other element.

Also as @Abdul said it should be `id` not `idName`.

```
function createDivTag() {
   var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
   newDiv.id = "newtask";
   newDiv.innerHTML += document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
   document.body.appendChild(newDiv) //Add the item to the body
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set id not idName  add created div to body before `getElementById`

```
newDiv.id = "newtask";
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to serve your purpose.

Suppose you have input field name **button**. If it's clicked it then a new  div will added inside the span named **area**.

So the HTML will be something like this

```
<input type="input" id="button" value="New Div"/>
<span id="area"></span>
```

And here is the script

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $('<div/>').attr({
       'id' : "myDiv"
    }).addClass('circle').css({
        'top' : e.pageY - 20,
        'left' : e.pageX - 20
    }).appendTo('#area');

    $("#myDiv").html($("#button").val());
});
```

You can checkout the simple working jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/CutPp/262/

Comment: Thank you. But the essential point is to make it using JS without any framework.